# In the IPA transcription do I need to show the global fall/rise before or after the stressed syllable?

Tags: ipa, inflection, intonation

I put the global fall symbol (down arrow) after the stressed syllable because it makes more sense to me. The last content word in a though group is where final inflection usually occurs, the syllable is stressed but then it falls.

[image]

However I checked Wikipedia on the global rise and fall and I noticed the arrows appear before the stress mark. Is that necessary or it is up to a personal preference?

Comment: You can't go down if you don't go up first. The global fall starts with the stressed syllable.

Comment: >> You can't go down if you don't go up first. << That is true. So, do you mean the arrow should be in front of the stressed syllable, like so: `↘ˈhæp ənd` ?

Comment: +1 There are different conventions. You can't do it here (because you can't do underlining), but one method is to put the symbols before the word, but underline the tonic syllable/nucleus. See John Wells's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35E77XOE_rk)

Comment: You should definitely see the [English Phonetics Archive](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=english+phonetics+archive). Especially those videos posted by Patricia Ashby, Michael Ashby, John Wells and Jane Setter.